# WordPress tinymce default link's target

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm trying to edit the WordPress TinyMCE editor so all the links has the target = "_blank". I've tried with jquery to set the 'Open link in new tab' checkbox to be always checked but, no results. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with the `default_link_target` setting in your TinyMCE configuration:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/link/#default_link_target

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle of this in action:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/31faab

To do this in Wordpress you will need to create a simple plugin that modifies this setting as TinyMCE is loaded.  It would look something like this:

```
<?php
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'add_my_options', 1000);

function add_my_options($opt) {
    $opt['default_link_target'] = "_blank";

    return $opt;  //you must return $opt to not break things
}
?>
```

If you have never created a WP plugin they are not hard to build and there are plenty of examples on the web.

Comment: Thank you. In the Fiddle works fine, but in wordpress context it is a little different. If I could locate the exact js file in which i should modify it, i'l let anyone know.

Comment: @Adrian - see my edits above - you just need to build a small WP plugin to add this change.